# Facebook Page Widget Share button showing "App Not Setup"

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a company facebook website and would like to include Facebook Page widget in the company homepage.

From the facebook page widget page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin), I embed the following code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/XXX" data-width="500" data-height="500" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/XXX"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/XXX">XXX</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

The facebook widget generated have a share button on it but when I click on it, it display the below error msg:

> App Not Set Up: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.

My Company account do not have any Facebook App Setup and from what I understand, a Facebook App is not needed to Facebook Page Plugin

Any idea? Many thanks!